Telepathic female alien in the Antarctic
I'm looking for a movie from the late 50's or early 60's about a female alien invader from a frigid planet who "lands" in the Antarctic (Arctic?) near a research station manned by 3 scientists. She had telepathic/hypnotic powers and wore rather skimpy clothing for the weather (somewhat like Vena from Rocky Jones). Thought it was called Deep Freeze but can't find it under that title. I think it was an American international film. Saw it on TV when I was 9 or 10 so it was dated by 1965. Any ideas? 

The Thing's original version, The Thing from Another World involves an alien crash-landing near an Arctic research station.

You are right about everything except one. Deep Freeze was the title of an episode of the television show, Warner Brothers Presents. An IMDb comment reads thus:

Allison Hayes is a beautiful, but dangerous, visitor from another planet. Her race of aliens can't stand heat, and can live only in sub-zero temperatures. Seems a group of American scientists is installing a weather-recording machine in the coldest region of the South Pole. Just then, this space-girl lands at their Antarctic weather station, and that's when strange things begin to happen. First, a mysterious electronic force knocks out their radio transmitter, and then members of the expedition start disappearing. The cause of all this havoc is the female alien from space (Allison Hayes), wearing a short skirt, while the humans are freezing and wearing thick parkas. This episode was rerun numerous times, from 1959 - 1962, often listed as a "movie" on TV channels airing science fiction films. Seems this episode borrowed the basic idea from the classic movie "The Thing from Another World" (1951), but with Allison being a sexy alien, as opposed to James Arness being a giant, scary alien. This is the kind of film that could best be viewed when presented by a late-night horror host like Sammy Terry, whose "Nightmare Theatre" thrilled young fans in Indianapolis in the 1960s. It's been a long time since I saw this show, and if it ever turns up on TV again, it will probably not be as scary or exciting as I vaguely remember it, but it will certainly be nostalgic.

